# Digital Certificate Signatures

Tags: certificate, digital-signature

Ok I'm sure this is obvious and I am missing something very fundamental here. We are sending an http request to a server. To prove it is us who is sending the request, we attach a certificate to it.

This certificate has a trusted CA, so the server knows that the certificate is genuine.

The bit I don't get is that we say to the server, ok trust certificates from Comodo let's say. Fine. So I send the request, it says I am 'Company A' and this is certified by Comodo.

Our clients who run the server just want to know who the CA is so they can trust it. Makes sense. But surely something else in the certificate needs checking to like the embedded company name? Otherwise I could go buy another certificate for my own personal company say, and get it from Comodo and that certificate would be valid according to the server too.

Please enlighten me!

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how a person at a web browser going to a web site for 'Company A' can be sure that it really is 'Company A' and not an imposter with a certificate from 'Company B' issued by the same trusted CA (Comodo).

The quick answer is that the browser *does* check the name on the certificate, not just whether it trusts the issuing CA.  The Subject field in a certificate is a Distinguished Name (DN) that looks something like this:

CN = www.google.com, O = Google Inc, L = Mountain View, S = California, C = US

The browser can check that the CN (Canonical Name) matches what you entered in your browser (https://www.google.com/) to be sure that you're at the right site.  Sometimes the CN does not match, but the certificate includes Subject Alternative Names that include a name that does match.  In either case the certificate includes the web site that you are attempting to load, so you can validate that it is the correct certificate for that site.

In addition there are many other checks that are (or could be) done:
* Check that current date and time is within the validity period for the certificate
* Check that the certificate is not revoked (using CRL or OCSP)
* Check that the signature is valid and signed by a trusted CA
* Check that the signing CA is actually a CA (Key Usage field in CA's certificate)
* Check the usage of the certificate itself to be sure it is a server certificate
* Check that the public key is strong enough (e.g., at least 2048 bit RSA)
* Check that the signature algorithm is strong enough (e.g., SHA256RSA vs. SHA1RSA)
* Check that the validity period is short enough (e.g., 3 years or less for servers)